# Spring Tool Suite: remove "cached" errors?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, ide

I had an XML-config that had an error in it (it referred to a missing constructor with no/empty parameters), once the constructor was created, and thus this error fixed, the error was still marked in the XML-file. I moved the line causing the error, but the error now moved on to the next line, but text at the marked line still referring to the original faulty bean-definition.

Being a Maven-project I tried to do all the maven update-commands, I rebuilt, restarted the IDE, restarted the PC but the error persisted.

As a final attempt to get rid of this error I removed almost all entries in the XML-file, apart from the usual xmlns-entries in the beginning. The error was now gone.

I then added the beans, one by one, and the error never showed up - as expected since the error was fixed.

This leads me to think: is there an "error cache" or something that one can cleanup or somehow refresh?

Are there an easier way to clean up such "old" errors?

Comment: "Project" > "Clean..." clears the list of errors and rebuilds it from scratch. Not sure if this applies to XML validation errors too, though.

Comment: I'll try it the next time this error occurs.

Comment: Project -> Clean worked like a charm! Wish I could add this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Kryger" said, Go to "Project" in the menu, and then choose "Clean" option. All errors gone!